# Unable to reload/redisplay PDF in WkWebView; but RTF apparently works

Tags: pdf, swiftui, webkit

**Scenario:**   TabbedUI with Tab #1 being a WkWebView displaying a **PDF** of general information (**Info**).

**Problem:** When I exit tab #1 (**info**) for another tab (ex. **search**), and return....I get an empty PDF with the following error message in the console:

[image]

> Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not
> find specified service

However this  *doesn't happen*  when I use a standard .rtf (Rich Text Format) file.

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct IntroSwiftUI: View {

    var body: some View {
        Webview()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }

}

// =====================================================================================================

struct Webview: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ReadMe", withExtension: "pdf") else {
            print("Inside Webview: unable to reload ReadMe.")
            return WKWebView()
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let wkWebview = WKWebView()
        wkWebview.load(request)
        wkWebview.scrollView.bounces = false

        return wkWebview
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

I just want a static PDF to be available for viewing whenever the user which to read some documentation (with embedded images).  But apparently it tries to rebuild and gets lost.

Do I need to do something 'special' with the PDF, like release it when exiting & re-create it upon return?  
That seems totally inefficient.

Comment: Why don't you use PDFView to display pdf? I never experienced such an issue with PDFView

Comment: I honestly forgot about PDFView.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per suggestion, 
Use the PDFView paradigm.

Here is my revised (correct) code for PDF viewing:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        // Create a `PDFView` and set its `PDFDocument`.
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
    }
}

struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL

    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}

// =====================================================================================================

struct IntroSwiftUI: View {
    var body: some View {
        if let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ReadMe", withExtension: "pdf") {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Introduction")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(Font.Weight.medium)
            PDFKitView(url: documentURL)
        }
        } else {
            Text("Sorry, No PDF")
        }
    }
}
```